# Expectation of Linear Search Algorithm running time.

Tags: algorithms, expected-value

Given an array $A[1],A[2],\cdots,A[n]$ , The Linear Search Algorithm wants to find if the array contain an element which the value is $x$. The Algorithm works like this , it starts from $i=1$,then step by step check whether $A[i] = x$ until $i = n$ , if it happens , then the algorithm terminate and return the index $i$.

So if the array contains exactly an element such that its value is $x$. The expectation running time of the algorithm is
$$E[X] = 1\cdot \frac{1}{n}+2\cdot \frac{1}{n}+ \cdots + n \cdot \frac{1}{n} = \frac{n+1}{2}$$
X is the random variable represents the running time. This situation is easy to understand.

My question is what if the array contains $k$ elements such that their value are $x$. What is the expecation running time of the Linear Search Algorithm? If I follow the step by above, it will give a mess expression that i can't simplify.
$$E[X] = \Sigma_{i}i\cdot \frac{\binom{n-i+1}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}} $$

Actually this is a question from Problem 5.2(f) of Introduction to Algorithms(CLRS). There is an [answer](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Eajl213/CLRS/Ch5.pdf)(Page 10) to this question doing it in this way. First define $X$ be the random variable which gives the number of elements examined before the algorithm terminates.Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable that the $i^{th}$ element of the array is examined. The expectation of $X$ will be
$$E[X] = E[X_1] +\cdots +E[X_n]$$
Now we need to determine each expectation of $E[X_i]$. The answer says " If $i$ is an index such that $A[i] \neq x$ then $P(X_i) = \frac{1}{k+1}$ since we examine it only if it occurs before every one of the $k$ indices that contains $x$". I couldn't understand why the probability will be $P(X_i) = \frac{1}{k+1}$. And it sounds like so obvious... Could there be a more detailed explanation to the probability?

Answer (score 0):

Let S be the set of the n elements in which there are k and only k elements that have value x. For each element w, let I be the indicator if w is examined or not, that is, I(w) = 1 if w is examined and 0 if w is not examined. X, the number of elements being examined, will be the sum of I(w) for all w in S. Accordingly, E[X] will be the sum of E[I(w)]=P{I(w)=1}.

For w that has a value x, the chance of w being examined is the chance that w is at the first position of a permutation of the k x-valued elements. Therefore it's 1/k.

For w that has a value not being x, the chance of x being examined is the chance that w is at the first position of a permutation of all the k x-valued elements plus element w. Therefore it's 1/(k+1).

There are k elements that have value x and n-k elements that are not equal to x, so the sum of all these probabilities will be k*(1/k) + (n-k)*(1/(k+1)) = (n+1)/(k+1).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).